# From which book is this quote? - "I stick my finger in existence — it smells of nothing"

Tags: existentialism, quote, kierkegaard

I'm looking for a work by Kierkgaard in which he wrote this quote.

Comment: The quote is from Kirkegaards book "Repetition" according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repetition_(Kierkegaard_book)

Comment: This is it. "Repetition" is well worth a read IF you like Kierkegaard's more literary, rambling works. If you prefer the slightly more rigid Kierkegaard of "Philosophical Crumbs" "The Sickness Unto Death" and "Concluding Unscientific Postscript....". If you're not into the literary Kierkegaard, though, the book is not necessary to understand his work.

Comment: Thank you. I'll definitely check it out.